# mpi send and recv all processes to one another

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to send data between all processes where I have an array on each process such as

```
int local_data[] = {0*rank,1*rank,2*rank,3*rank};
```

I have a corresponding flag array where each value in that array points to which process I should be sending this value, for example:

```
int part[] = {0,1,3,2};
```

so this means local_data[0] should go to process with rank 0
local_data[2] should go to process with rank 3 and so on.
The values in the flag arr changes from one process to the other ( all within range 0-P-1 where P is the total number of processes available) .

Using this, What I am currently doing is :

```
for(int i=0; i<local_len; i++){
        if(part[i] != rank){
            MPI_Send(&local_data[i], 1,MPI_INT, part[i], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Recv(&temp,1, MPI_INT, rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status );
            recvbuf[j] = temp;
            j++;
        }
        else{
            recvbuf[j] = local_data[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
```

where I am only sending and receiving data if the part[i] != rank, to avoid sending and receiving from the same process

recvbuf is the array I receive the values in for each process. It can be longer than the initial local_data length.

I also tried

```
MPI_Sendrecv(&local_data[i], 1,MPI_INT, part[i], 0, &temp, 1, MPI_INT, rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

the program gets stuck for both ways

How do I go about solving this?

Is the All-to-All collective the way to go here?

Comment: a given `rank` sends to `part[i]` but receive from `rank` (e.g. itself) so this is going to hang. Note your pattern assumes each rank send exactly one element to all the other ranks. depending on how communications are ordered, it might deadlock anyway. `MPI_Alltoallv()` looks like the way to go here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @GillesGouaillardet advice, I used [MPI_AlltoAllv](https://www.rookiehpc.com/mpi/docs/mpi_alltoallv.php)

to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that your send call goes to a dynamically determined target, but there is no corresponding logic to determine which processes need to do a receive at all, and if so, from where.

If the logic of your application implies that everyone will send to everyone, then you can use `MPI_Alltoall`.

If everyone sends to some, but you know that you will receive exactly four messages, then you can combine `MPI_Isend` for the sends and `MPI_Recv` from `ANY_SOURCE`. Note that you need `Isend` because your code will deadlock, strictly speaking. It may work if your MPI has a "eager mode" for small messages.

If the number of sends and the targets are entirely random, then you need something like `MPI_Ibarrier` to detect that all is over and done.

But I suspect you're leaving out major information here. Why is the length of `local_data` 4? Is the `part` array a permutation? Et cetera.

Comment: Yeah you're right about leaving out some information. So the length of local_data is dynamic(could be any length) and part array is just an array that I use to "partition" (values of part are from 0 to P-1, where P is the number of processes) the data such that I can send each element from ```local_data``` to the corresponding process value in ```part```. I was able to use MPI_AlltoAllv to solve this